# How to access the value of the input text field in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

The code of the text field is:

```
<s:iterator value="paramSimple" var="param" status="iteratorStatus">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" text_id="<s:property value="#iteratorStatus.index" />" value= "<s:property value=" #param.value.split(':')[1] " />"/>
</td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

How do i access the value of the text field in JS function?

I tried using

```
$("input[text_id='1']")
```

but it shows the input element instead of the value

Comment: inspect element and check what is actually rendered on html.

Answer (score 3):

you can access the value of an input by using `.value`

something like this

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

```
const input = document.getElementById("input");
console.log(input.value); //console logs the value of the input

console.log($("#input").value); //jquery
```

but obviously you can target it not only with ids, in this case you want to target it with `text_id` so just add `.value` behind it to target the value

```
$("input[text_id='1']").value
```